# Spring Data JPA findBy optional variables

Tags: java, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I know I can make custom queries by adding a method to my repository interface. For example if I have the Person entity.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String dateOfBirth;

    // All applicable getters and setters
}
```

My repository interface can look like:

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

But what if I want to search for all parameters and all combination of parameters. For example if I want to search by:

- firstName (by itself)
- LastName (by itself)
- gender (by itself)
- dateOfBirth (by itself)
- firstName and LastName
- firstName and gender
- firstName and dateOfBirth
- lastName and gender
- lastName and dateOfBirth
- gender and dateOfBirth
- firstName and lastName and gender
- firstName and lastName and dateOfBirth
- firstName and lastName and dateOfBirth and gender

Does that mean I have to create all those repository methods in the interface. Is there a way to search by all parameters optionally. Something along the lines of

```
findBy(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String dateOfBirth)
```

and if whatever is consuming the REST API for example would like to search only on firstName and lastName it would call

```
http://localhost/people/search/findBy?firstName=John&firstName=Smith
```

**UPDATE**: I was able to solve this, with some SQL trickery In the PersonRepository interface I did something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person p WHERE ((:firstName IS NULL) OR (:firstName IS NOT NULL AND p.firstName = :firstName)) AND ((:lastName IS NULL) OR (:lastName IS NOT NULL AND p.lastName = :lastName)) AND ((:gender IS NULL) OR (:gender IS NOT NULL AND p.gender = :gender)) AND ((:dateOfBirth IS NULL) OR (:dateOfBirth IS NOT NULL AND p.dateOfBirth = :dateOfBirth )) ")
        Page<Person> findBy(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("gender") String gender, @Param("dateOfBirth") String dateOfBirth, Pageable page);
```

The end point gets called this way http://localhost:8080/people/search/findBy?firstName=John&lastname=&gender=&dateOfBirth=

you should get a list of all people named "John"

Answer (score 3):

Make use of find by example.
I have done it for employee.

***Repository:***

```
//skipped lines    
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example
//skipped lines
interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey>{
    List<Employee> findAll(Example<Employee> employee);
}
```

***Usage:***

```
// Prepare Employee key with all available search by keys (6 in my case)
EmplyeeKey key = new EmplyeeKey();
key.setField1("field1_value");
key.setField2("field2_value");
//Setting remaining 4 fields

// Create new Employee ans set the search key
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setEmployeeKey(key);


// Call the findAll by passing an Example of above Employee object
List<Employee> result = employeeRepository.findAll(Example.of(employee));
```