# How to write optional query in JPA with Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on post api call in which 8 parameters and we need to create a dynamic based on the request.

For example: `getList(String param1, String param2)`

Here, if `param1` is null then query will be: `select * from table1 t where t.param2=param2;`

If both are not not null then: `select * from table1 t where t.param1=param1 and t.param2=param2;`

I am using Postgres Database.

I saw few solutions that were discussed already like this one [Spring Data JPA findBy optional variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052493/spring-data-jpa-findby-optional-variables)

My Query:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM PaperMasterTest p " +
            "WHERE ((:uuid IS NULL) OR (p.userId = :uuid))" +
            " AND ((:schoolId IS NULL) OR (p.schoolId = :schoolId))" +
            " AND ((:boardId IS NULL) OR (p.boardId = :boardId))" +
            " AND ((:classId IS NULL) OR (p.classId = :classId))" +
            " AND ((:syllabusId IS NULL) OR (p.subjectIds = :syllabusId))" +
            " AND ((:paperCategoriesId IS NULL) OR (p.groupId = :paperCategoriesId))")
        List<PaperMasterTest> getPaperList(@Param("uuid") String uuid,
                                           @Param("schoolId") Integer schoolId,
                                           @Param("boardId") Integer boardId,
                                           @Param("classId") Integer classId,
                                           @Param("syllabusId") Integer syllabusId,
                                           @Param("paperCategoriesId") Integer paperCategoriesId);
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        papermaste0_.paper_id as paper_id1_1_,
        papermaste0_.board_id as board_id4_1_,
        papermaste0_.class_id as class_id2_1_,
        papermaste0_.draft_id as draft_id5_1_,
        papermaste0_.paper_category_id as paper_c10_1_,
        papermaste0_.is_draft as is_draft7_1_,
        papermaste0_.paper_name as paper_n16_1_,
        papermaste0_.school_id as school_22_1_,
        papermaste0_.syllabus_id as syllabu24_1_,
        papermaste0_.test_id as test_id25_1_,
        papermaste0_.paper_marks as paper_m15_1_,
        papermaste0_.total_question as total_q26_1_,
        papermaste0_.paper_time as paper_t18_1_,
        papermaste0_.user_id as user_id28_1_ 
    from
        table1 papermaste0_ 
    where
        (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.user_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.school_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.board_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.class_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.syllabus_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or papermaste0_.paper_category_id=?
        )
2022-01-08 13:33:49.590 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.590 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.591 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.592 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.592 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [11] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.592 TRACE 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [12] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2022-01-08 13:33:49.667  WARN 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P18
2022-01-08 13:33:49.667 ERROR 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
2022-01-08 13:33:49.681 ERROR 17343 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar:42.2.22]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.getPaperList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.extramarks.test_creation.service.PaperListingServiceImpl.getPaperList(PaperListingServiceImpl.java:34) ~[main/:na]
    at com.extramarks.test_creation.controller.PaperListingController.getPaperListing(PaperListingController.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

**I also tried type casting** like `(:param1::int is NULL)` for integer and `(:param1::varchar is null)` for text.

Earlier my query contains timestamp and boolean fields also, I thought error may be coming because of that but even after removing those things error is coming.

Is there any other way through which I can achieve this in Postgres with JPA?

Comment: You query seems fine to me. Can you please check the datatype defined in the table for that column ? Also, make similar field for the fields in your `MasterTest` dto

Comment: @user404 I crossed checked several times but don't know what is creating an issue here. Data type at entity and dto both are same as database column data type.

Comment: Is there any thing else that can create issue, and I need to check?

Comment: @user404 I was doing some variation so when I removed the uuid part of query then starts working fine. uuid datatype in database is text. There is some issue when I am passing the string.

Comment: can you show me the `PaperMasterTest` table's SQL script or column definition for that table please?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.paper_master
(
    paper_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    paper_category_id integer,
    board_id integer,
    class_id integer,
    syllabus_id integer,
    paper_marks integer,
    paper_time integer,
    is_draft boolean DEFAULT false,
    school_id integer,
    user_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    creation_date timestamp without time zone,
    draft_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT assess_paper_master_pkey PRIMARY KEY (paper_id)
)

Comment: @user404 sorry for delay, it was giving error in case of boolean and timestamp also.

Comment: I think the case is for `text` type here. May be, you need to add `@Lob` in your field for that Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use spring boot specification, which enables you to write daynamic and optional query. It is somehow complicated but I will help you surely.

I use the following resource

https://kreepcode.com/spring-data-specification/
https://github.com/attacomsian/code-examples/tree/master/spring-data-jpa/jpa-specifications

Comment: Thanks, I will try it with specification and I will connect with you if I will stuck somewhere.